# Webview control in android

Tags: android, webview

I want to be able to put a webpage within a restricted view, like only use part of the screen. This is so I can add buttons under the video and an image on top.

Is this possible and please can you tell me how to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try typing the title of your question into your favorite search engine? ;)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: obviously, that developers guide is no help. Only for basic things. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

? The developer's guide is pretty helpful for all sorts of things. However, just define a linear layout that is the size and at the positioning that you require, then pop the webview inside that.

Note: I assume you are using xml to define layouts.